# ios opengl es render texture on clean C

Tags: android, ios, c, opengl-es, textures

sorry for my english
I want to draw textures on clean C, no objective c! 
that it is necessary to write a library for ios / android

I draw

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer{
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];//a string
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}

- (void)drawView {


[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];//a string

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);

Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(3686400);
memcpy(byteData, [texData bytes]+kon, 3686400);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1280, 720, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteData);
free(byteData);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];//a string
}
```

how to get rid of these lines, which are tied to objective c?

```
1 [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
2 [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
3 [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];</code>
```

Comment: since you have android tagged, is the reason you are trying to do this because you want to have code that works in both android and ios?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and still have this render to the screen in iOS. EAGLContext is an Objective-C object that is used to manage your OpenGL ES contexts, and you need to interact with it in order to render and display your scene.

However, you can wrap accesses to this in a function that changes its contents depending on what platform you are targeting. Compiler conditionals can help you do this.

Comment: @user1881371 - I'm not sure what you're saying. Again, you just need to encapsulate references to this in functions that change at compile-time based on what your target platform is.

Comment: create EAGLContext object to objective-c but use it in C, passed as arguments to the library, and the library will draw